# How to toggle a line comment in XAML for C# WPF in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, hotkeys

I have <kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd> set to toggle line comments globally in my C# project.

It does works when I'm editing `.cs` file.

[image: Editor.ToggleLineComment in Visual Studio Options.]

However, it does not work when editing XAML files.

[image: Sample XAML file.]

It does work if I press the comment and uncomment buttons

[image: Visual Studio toolbar with comment and uncomment buttons.]

But not with the hotkey I set.

Is there a different command I should use for toggling the XAML comment wrapper with a single hotkey?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the XAML editor does not use the `Editor.ToggleLineComment` shortcut. Instead it is:

- `Editor.CommentSelection` for commenting a line or selection in XAML
- `Editor.UncommentSelection` for uncommenting a line or selection in XAML

When pressing the shortcut, the XAML **line** will be commented out, if the cursor is placed anywhere in the line (no selection) or the selected characters are commented out, if you select a range of text.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for the answer, I found the solution (Working with VS 2022)

1. Open keyboard shortcuts
   [image]
2. In shortcut dialog box, find and select `Editor.CommentSelection`
3. Then select `Text Editor` under `Use shortcut in:` and set the shortcut key `Ctrl+/` (in my case)
4. Assign the key
   [image]
5. Repeat the process for `Editor.UncommentSelection`

Answer (score 0):

@John.

You can install Toggle Comment to make Editor.ToggleLineComment  work in XAMl code. Below is the Step:

1. Download and install Toggle Comment from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=munyabe.ToggleComment)
2. Restart VS.
3. Go to "Tools>Options...>Environment>Keyboard" and search for  "ToggleLineComment"  then bind it to your favorite key
4. Open  XAML code page, "Edit" -> "Advances" -> "Toggle Comment" to make the **Menu Placement**.

**Update:**

The result of the fourth step is shown in the picture below:
(What we need to note here is that the fifth step is executed in the XAML page)

[image]

Comment: Installing that extension makes no difference in the XAML editor

Comment: Hi, @Jhon. I updated the result diagram of the fourth step to the answer, you can check if it is consistent with yours. And my Visual Studio version is **Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.9.4**.