How to add comments into a Xaml file in WPF using Edit.ToggleLineComment in Visual Studio 2022
I'm struggling to use the Edit.ToggleLineComment keybinding in Visual Studio 2022 when it comes to .xaml files.
My shortcut is set correctly as shown in this screenshot:

It works in my .cs files but does not add <!-- when I press my shortcut in .xaml files.
How can I make this happen in Visual Studio 2022?
Is this simply not possible?
Thanks for the help.

I don't know if info in this other link is correct or up to date, but it seems to address your question.
see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67391916/how-to-toggle-a-line-comment-in-xaml-for-c-sharp-wpf-in-visual-studio-2019

@RichK I saw it but unfortunately you can't put the same shortcut for both Comment and Uncomment, so I can't have the toggle effet :(

If MSVC doesn't support it natively, maybe you could try an extension. Perhaps: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TechHypno.ToggleComment

@Rich K That extension doesn't work well, I tried it and it allows you to comment but not to uncomment. The toggle does not seem to be working well.

@FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows What is the difference between Edit.CommentSelection and Edit.ToggleLineComment? Its seems to me that Edit.CommentSelection can comment out single lines as well ( even without selection, it is enough to the cursor to be placed somewhere in the code). What am I missing?

@bazsisz I can't comment and uncomment with the same shortcut with CommentSelection. I can with Toggle.

Because that command is not available for XAML editor context.



Ah, so this is a Microsoft problem, and I should use third party tools... sad
